# How to align <tr> element based on the other <tr> element that is above

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have 20  tags or so and they all have absolute position. They are dynamically generated based on the response I get from an XML and they currently are aligned next to each other.

How can I align them to be 4 on each row, but with the 5th  tag to be exactly under the 1st  tag, the 6th tag to be under the 2nd and so on. Every tag has a different height.
Normally, the first 4 should not require any aligment.

Here is the structure:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
     <tr>
     <tr>
     ........
     <tr>
     <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my CSS for the  tags:

```
.innerContent tr {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F3F3F3;
      border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;    
      float: left;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 5px 25px;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      transition: all 1s ease 0s;
      z-index: 5;
}
```

I doubt this can be achieved with CSS so I'm thinking JQuery. Everything I tried only made them all overlap 4 by 4.

Comment: Where are you TDs?  Your HTML example is incomplete.

Comment: Just as a note, I tried Bootstrap Fluid Layout, but the result wasn't as expected. It aligned the whole row based on the one above. I am looking for a way to align a <tr> element based on the one above.

Comment: What's the content of the rows?  Is it tabular data? If not, I would recommend you NOT use `<tr>`s/`<td>`s for the purpose of layout and go with `<div>`s or `<ul>`/`<li>`s

Comment: Is `position:absolute` necessary?

Comment: I don't understand why are you floating the rows?

Comment: I did not think that the TDs are relevant, as I am thinking that in order to achieve my question, it will require the height if the TRs

Comment: and can you explain what you define as *tag*?

Comment: If you give us some context maybe we can provide a better way of going about this?

Comment: anpsmn - Position absolute is not necessary, I just tried it this way.

Comment: the float remained in the code, my bad, from when I was using the position:relative

Comment: by tag, I mean the tr element

Comment: Context: I have a page that has a dataTable in JSF. I have one column, and that column gets populated with information that I receive in an XML response. I have hotels in the response, and for every hotel I have in the response, a tr element is created

Comment: Should I provide more explanations or information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, I would HIGHLY recommend AGAINST using a `table` for this.  It doesn't seem like you are populating it with tabular data, so you are just using it as a layout tool. And for what you want to do that is a very bad tool.

Since you mentioned Twitter Bootstrap above, I would recommend you utilize their [scaffolding grid system](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html).  To give a a very basic example, take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WqPqP/) on how I would approach this.

For completion sake, here is the HTML I used in the jsFiddle. This will line up 4 columns per row with a width of 220px each (based on their container width of 940px). If you want a different container size, you just need to tweak the width slightly.

Of course this requires the use of the Bootstrap CSS:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3">Hotel 1</div>
  <div class="span3">Hotel 2</div>
  <div class="span3">Hotel 3</div>
  <div class="span3">Hotel 4</div>
  <div class="span3">Hotel 5</div>
  <div class="span3">Hotel 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Steven. I already tried this option, as I wrapped 4 tr elements into a div with the `class='row'` and set the class for every tr element to 'span3', but it did not worked as I expected. The reason why I am using a table is because my web application is made in Java and I am using JSF, so in order to generate the rows I am using:

Comment: I looked for an alternative where it would be with divs and spans, but could not find one, so I am stuck with a table

Comment: Of course Twitter Bootstrap scaffolding won't work on the `tr`s.  That's why I gave you the example with `div`s.  I don't know much about JSF, but it can't be that hard to loop over some `div`s instead of a table.  Instead of spending lots of time to find a hack to make your table line up correctly, I would rather invest time in creating correct HTML... but that's just me.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you sir, I guess I would rather do that than to try and find a hack.

Answer (score 0):

i think You need stuff like this:

**jQuery**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $mt = $('<table>').attr('id', 'myTable');
    for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
     var $row = $("<tr>").appendTo($mt);
        for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
           $row.append($('<td/>').text(y * 4 + x + 1).appendTo($mt));
        }
         $mt.append($row);
      }
      $("#myTable").html($mt);
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/673tG/1/

Comment: It works, but not exactly how I would have wanted. Thank you for the time. I will pick Steve's answer as I will be taking his advice. Thanks !